# kable and kableExtra not rendering in pdf from markdown document

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am trying to render a table into a pdf using kable in a markdown document generated from a shiny app. It renders OK until I use any functionality from kableExtra (`column_spec` in the code below) at which point I get the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array
> arg.

The problem seems pretty basic and I'm not the first to have this issue, but other solutions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011425/kableextra-error-in-markdown-when-rendering-to-pdf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704876/problems-rendering-table-using-r-markdown-kable-and-kableextra)) haven't helped. The table renders OK as HTML but it seems that kableExtra doesn't seem to know that it is rendering latex. If I change the `knitr.table.format` to `"pandoc"` it renders but still errors of the `column_spec` line. Any ideas?

### UI.R

```
fluidPage(
  title = 'Download a PDF report',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText(),
      div("Create a Mark Down Document"),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton('downloadReport')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('regPlot')
    )
  )
)
```

### Server.R

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)

function(input, output) {

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )

}
```

### Report.Rmd

````
 Test kable:
 
```{r}

 auto_set_format <- function() { 
   if (knitr::is_latex_output()) { 
     options(knitr.table.format = "latex") 
   } else { 
     options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
   } 
 }

auto_set_format()

tbl <- knitr::kable(mtcars[1:6, 1:6], caption = 'A subset of mtcars.') 

# THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBEM WHEN WRITING TO PDF. COMMENT OUT AND IT WORKS OK
tbl <- tbl %>% column_spec(3, color = "#62BD19")

tbl
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `column_spec()` you need to give an additional Latex package to `knitr`, i.e. change your report to

````
---
title: "Example Table"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{dcolumn}
---
 Test kable:
 
```{r}

 auto_set_format <- function() { 
   if (knitr::is_latex_output()) { 
     options(knitr.table.format = "latex") 
   } else { 
     options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
   } 
 }

auto_set_format()

tbl <- knitr::kable(mtcars[1:6, 1:6], caption = 'A subset of mtcars.') %>% 
              column_spec(3, color = "#62BD19")

tbl
```
````

and you will be able to produce both reports.

Comment: Fantastic, that's perfect! One question though, How could I have known that without posting in SO? Is there any documentation that tells you what latex packages you need when using different R packages for markdown?

Comment: I would say experience :D This happens in rmd quite often tbh